# Maintain the queryset object through http requests

Tags: django, http, django-forms, httprequest

I have an use case that is completed in 3 screens. In the first screen, the user sees a list of objects and can apply some dynamic filters. He can add rules like: "phone_number contains 85" "phone_number doesn't contains 9" "name is equals to Fabio"

After user clicks in apply filters button, i refresh the screen and show only the objects that match the rules.

In the same screen i have actions like admin actions in django admin where i can update a list of objects. If the user selects 3 objects, i pass the 3 IDs to the second screen. But i would like to update 250k rows at once, so my idea is to pass the filters to the second screen to mount the queryset again.

Is there an easy way to maintain the queryset object from one page to another ? If i could put the select of the queryset inside a html field to read it and create a django queryset object again it would be great.

Any better ideas ?

Comment: have a look at this link. I've used this method to have get parameters stick around http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/09/02/django-sticky-url-query-parameters-per-view.html

Comment: denvaar, thanks for your answer, but i would like to pass the queryset in a request, not put in session, because the user can leave the second page without complete the use case. It could be great if i can put a field form of type queryset. :-)